# How do you change the stack width/offset in radare2?

Tags: radare2, debuggers

Currently, my stack view is 0x10 (16) bytes long.

[image: Stack View]

How do I change it so that the stack view is 8 bytes long?

Edit:
I have tried tabbing into the stack window, pressing e, and then typing `pxr 256@r:SP` and it did not work. Here is my results
[image]

Edit 2: This DOES work, I just need to press `i` a few more times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the Stack panel by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then press the <kbd>I</kbd> key a couple of times (in my case two times) and you get a view like this:

[image: Stack view of 8 bytes wide]

Edit: This works if your panel has the pxr command (I'm not sure if that is the default), so if it doesn't work, you can try this:

Select the Stack panel using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, press the <kbd>e</kbd> key, type `pxr 256@r:SP`

then you can use the <kbd>I</kbd> key as I described before.

Comment: Is there a way to make this default at start up?

Comment: I would think that loading a layout at startup would be good enough, but for me it seems to be bugged out for some reason. 

You can try to save the layout with this command: v= name

To load it at startup you can add this to the commandline: r2 -c 'v name'

I'm not sure how to do this automatically, but in my case it changes the command of the Stack panel anyway, so in my case it's useless.