# How to make the default stack width/offset 8 bytes when debgging in radare2

Tags: debugging, radare2

If you start radare2 in debugging mode like:

```
r2 -d /usr/bin
```

you'll be prompted with something similar to:

[image: prompt]

If you press <kbd>V</kbd> for the prompt, you get debugging view with panels. Then, if you select the Stack panel using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, press the <kbd>E</kbd> key, type `pxr 256@r:SP`, you get this view (this is thanks to this [answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/how-do-you-change-the-stack-width-offset-in-radare2)), **you get what I'd like to be the default view**

[image: Ideal View]

How do I make the above window the default view for when I enter:
`r2 -d /usr/bin` and then <kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple panel layouts configured and save/load them from the menus. if you want that to be shipped by default please open a ticket in github or send a pullrequest changing the default layout when in debugger mode. It's a better place to discuss than this forum, where i hopefully plan to be more active these days)

Thanks